# RegisterChannel error: "is a method, but used as type" in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a problem in C#. I am trying to make a project for a Mini Market and I want to bind it with a Server.

In our lesson, we did a little project, where we created an Client, a Server and a Class as a reference. Those were Console Application in C#. And it worked.

I wanted now to make the client in windows form application but the problem is when I want to register the channel!! it shows me an error.

Here is the print screen image:

[image]

The error is like:

> "System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(System.Remting.Channels.IChannel))
>   is a 'method' but it used like a 'type'

I have added the namespace for Channel. I tried to change the .Net Framework (i tried 4.0 Client, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a second to see this, but the problem is that you are making the call outside of a method block.

If you want this to occur on construction, then you need to move your code into the `Form1()` code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HttpChannel chan = new HttpChannel();
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);
    //Shitja code
}
```

if you need the `chan` variable later, then you can do this:

```
HttpChannel chan;
public Form1()
{
    ...
    chan = new HttpChannel();
    ...
}
```

Also, since 2.0 [MSDN has marked this method as obsolete in favor of the overload with 2 params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223155%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)